# Python how to pass class function from instance to another class

Tags: python, class

I have a class of `Player` with a number of attributes to measure their overall state. I have a second class of `Character` (Class Type) that sets up some unique configurations for my players depending on their instance of character. Where I am having trouble, is calling a single generic function at the player level that measures the unique milestone goals for each character. i.e Check each player to see if they have reached their unique Milestone 1. I originally tried to do this with a series of conditional functions under the initialization, but this proved to be ill-advised in a class, so I moved it out to its own single function. Since doing this, it obviously fails because the attributes the function are checking for are in the parent class (`Player`) and not the class where the function is defined (`Character`).

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, player_num, name):
        self.character = Character(name)
        self.player_num = player_num
        self.name = name
        self.power = 0
        self.position = 1
        self.attributeLimit = 4
        self.attributes = []
        self.attachments = []
        self.collection = []
        self.visited = []
        self.setCharacterValues()
        self.ms1 = self.character.Milestone1 

        def setCharacterValues()
        #Loads Character instance data into the Player instance.

class Character:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.attributes = []
        self.attachments = []
        self.collection = []
        self.visited = []
        self.name = name
        if name == 'char x':
            self.attributes = [1,2,3]
            #etc.
        #etc.

    def Milestone1(self):
        if self.name == 'char x':
            if self.power >= 20:
                return True
            else:
                return False
        if self.name == 'char y':
            if self.position >= 5:
                return True
            else:
                return False
        #etc

for i in players:
    if i.ms1():
        print('Passed')
```

Now the only solution that I can think of, is to simply move the function from the `Character` class to the `Player` class. But this seems to be counter intuitive to me, because this function is measuring each unique characters ability to reach the milestone. It *feels* appropriate to leave it under Character, and I'm just missing an obvious step somewhere. Can anyone lend some assistance?

Comment: Why don't you use inheritance instead?

Comment: It was solved using SubClass / Inheritance. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please post the traceback error messages. I think the problem is in `Milestone1()` you check `self.power` and `self.position` but self refers to the instance of `Character` not `Player`, and character has no power or position attributes.

Here are 2 fixes I can think of:

1. **Inheritance**: If you make player a subclass of character, then player would have all of the attributes of character and therefore be able to call `ms1()`

   ```py
   class Player(Character):
       def __init__(self, player_num, name):
           # self.character = Character(name)  <-- not needed
           # self.ms1 = self.character.Milestone1  <-- not needed

           # since Player is a subclass of Character,
           # use super to init & it already has name and Milestone1
           super().__init__(name)  # Py3 usage
           # super(Player, self).__init__(name)  # Py2 usage
   ```

   I tested this out in [a simple example on repl.it](https://repl.it/@mikofski/ImpossiblePalegreenWrapper)
   and it works for me, try it by pressing play, output is `'n'`, then `'t'`.

   *Note: [in Python-2, the syntax for `super` is different than Python-3](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super), and you must also supply the subclass, `Player`, and the instance, `self` as args. I tested inheritance  with `super(Player, self).__init__(name)` in [this sample repl.it using Python-2](https://repl.it/@mikofski/RespectfulImpressiveMultitasking) and it also works.*

   *Also Note: [Python-2 classes should subclass `object` to create new-style classes](https://wiki.python.org/moin/NewClassVsClassicClass).*
2. **Composition**:Fix `Milestone1()` so it uses player as an argument, and therefore has access to power and position

   ```py
   class Character:
       # no change

       def Milestone1(self, player):
           if self.name == 'char x':
               if player.power >= 20:
                   return True
               else:
                   return False
   ```

   update `Player` too, passing the player instance to `Milestone1`

   ```py
   class Player:
       def __init__(self, player_num, name):
           self.character = Character(name)

           # self is the Player, lambda makes ms1 callable
           self.ms1 = lambda: self.character.Milestone1(self)
   ```

   Although then the `name` attribute isn't really used, and this seems a bit hacky, but I tested it in [this simple repl.it example](https://repl.it/@mikofski/UntidyHoneydewAccounting) and it also works.

In general, I think this is a good opportunity to use inheritance over composition. Ask yourself:

> Is a player a character? (Inheritance: #1)
>
> Does a player have a character? (Composition: #2)

Comment: Hi Mark, I'm responding from my phone, but I think Inheritance is exactly the solution I an expecting to solve this. I will review it tonight. Thank you!

Comment: This seems to work fine on Python3, but running my script in 2.7 I keep getting this error:(TypeError: must be type, not classobj) from the line super().__init__(name)

Comment: sorry in [Python-2, `super` is different](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super), you have to call `super(subclass, self).__init__(self, x, y, ...)`

Comment: but in Python-2, you should also subclass all your classes to `object`, Python-3 fixes that. I assumed you were using Python3 because you didn't use `object` in your classes, _e.g._ `class Character(object): # do stuff`

Comment: Note there's a typo in the comment above on `super` for Python-2. It should say `super(subclass, self).__init__(x, y, ...)` _i.e._ no `self` argument in `__init__`, just in `super` - oops!

Comment: So I took your example from Repl.it and moved it to 2.7 and made the change you suggested (shown below). Still getting the same error.
`class Char:
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name

  def ms1(self):
    if self.x > 2:
      return True
    return False

class Plyr(Char):
  def __init__(self, name):
    super(Plyr,self).__init__(name)
    self.x = 0
p = Plyr('Ivan')`

Comment: Nevermind, I missed what you said about defining the class as object: `class Character(object):` .  Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend initizliaing a power value in the Character class as well, or creating a generic method in the Character class and then overriding it in the Player class.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a container class `Player` that has a one-to-one relationship with the `Character`. You do not want to duplicate the attributes of Character (like `ms1` within `Player`, especially not during `__init__` before anything at all has happened in your game. Instead just access that Character's attributes from the Player instances whenever you need to check them:

```py
player = Player(player_num=42, name='Ivan')
# do some stuff with `player` and `player.character` as the game progresses
# then somewhere deep in the game...
if player.character.ms1:
    print("Congratulations on achieving your first milestone!")
```